# Avoiding differential_fingerprint for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ubuntu-20.04, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm trying to modify an extension for my own use which was working for a long time in developer mode. However I've a fresh installation of my Ubuntu with chrome verion 100.0.4896.88 , and this does not work anymore.

The extension is copy all urls (2.11_1), and when I try to load it, it results error, which leads to this line in the manifest file:

```
   "differential_fingerprint": "1.f8b0acda8f2f6141b440b147dd4ae9ae0869a46f2dd3884dc2a010007654eb66",
```

.

How can I avoid this error message if I modify the extension?
Or how I generate this type of fingerprint?

Comment: Delete this key, it's an internal temporary thing.

Comment: Well, I tried, but still have issue. it complains about the manifest version then. It's 2, and it does not accept it.

Comment: Is there any howto, how to modify an existing extension on local environment with the newest chrome?

Comment: It just warns about manifest version, you can ignore it.